# Solutions to linear differential equation of $n^{th}$ order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just wanted to know about the various available procedures for solving an $n^{th}$ order differential equation which is like $a_0y^n+a_1y^{n-1}+\cdots+a_ny^0=f(x)$, where in $a_0,a_1,\cdots ,a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $f(x)$ can be any function ( Transcendental too ).

Is there any closed form solution available ?

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention, apart from Variation Of Parameters or Undetermined Coefficients , or any form of guessing to get the solution. @Amzoti

Answer (score 3):

Yes. By using Lie point  symmetry.
In fact, there's no direct method for solving EDO. But with this method you can associate some transformations that take solutions in solutions. With this , it is possible to find quantities named generators and with this you can find te solutions.

You can see this in Hydon's or Stephani's books on solving ED by usin symmetries.

Comment: by the way, if you are interested in learning this method, please contact me [ if you want ], because I am starting to read the Stephani's book and I would be very glad on sharing information.

Comment: in fact, Variation Of Parameters, Undetermined Coefficients and variable substitution are all particular cases of using Lie point symmetry.

Comment: Apart from Lie Symmetry, is there any method?

Comment: Don't know. Do you know any other different procedure?

Comment: nope. Lie Symmetry sounds like the best option out there.